# Can I trigger an Azure DevOps build from Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration

We use Jenkins as our build orchestrator, and are just spiking the use of Azure DevOps for a particular project. Our build works fine, pulling code from Git and creating the artifacts we need, whether we trigger automatically from git or manually.

I still want Jenkins to be the orchestrator however, so that our pipeline is more obvious to people not in our team.

There is a lot of info about triggering Jenkins from DevOps, but I haven't found anything to support what we need. Is it possible, and can you share any examples please?

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger a build in Azure DevOps using its REST API. The [API for triggering build is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Basically it's a POST operation to the following endpoint:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0
```

And [authentication can be done using OAuth or Personal Access Token as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#create-the-request).

Depending on your technology of choice, [there may also be a client object model you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#client-libraries).

[A powershell sample can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110114/736079).

Comment: this looks perfect, thanks very much. I'd rather a REST call with OAuth than relying on plugins tbh.

Comment: Make sure that the request body looks like this `{ "definition": {"id": <your_pipeline_id>} }` You can get your list of pipelines at this URL `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done natively using Azure Pipeline Releases.

1. Create a [Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops#create-new) between Azure DevOps and your [Jenkins Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops#sep-jenkins)
2. Create a new Release Pipeline in the Releases tab under the Pipelines section in Azure Devops
3. [Add an artifact to the release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops#sep-jenkins) (on the left hand side). In the view that appears choose '4 more artifact sources' and Jenkins will appear.
4. Choose the Service Connection you created from the drop for the Jenkins connection then choose the Jenkins Job from the next drop down.

This makes is clearer for your devs to see what's going on. Whilst using rest is a good method it hides a lot of the work. This way anyone looking at the front page of a release can see the artifact sources.

HTH

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I take your point about keeping everything opbvious on the front page. Isn't the above triggering Jenkins from DevOps rather than the other way around though?

Comment: No it’s triggering DevOps from Jenkins. I can’t find better documentation on it but if you set up your service connection and set up a new pipeline and add Jenkins as an artefact hopefully you can see how it’ll work.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll take a look. We're really spiking at the moment, so its good to have a look at a few things.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get up and running. I was also using the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) to start the actual build.